# Bash script to rename all files in a directory

Tags: bash

I have a directory with a bunch of files names like this:

```
DetailedFeatureNameIntegrationTest.java
```

and I want to rename all the files to

```
DetailedFeatureNameIntegTest.java.
```

I just want to replace 'Integration' with 'Integ'
is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is your criterion, just replacing `Integration` with `Integ`?

Comment: Yes it is, I will edit the question to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure `bash`,

```
for f in *.java; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f//ration/}"
done
```

assuming you don't have a situation like both `DetailedFeatureNameIntegrationTest.java` and `DetailedFeatureNameIntegTest.java` already in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

With the perl `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/Integration/Integ/' *.java
```